# What does this image in Space Travel represent?

Tags: gaming, unix, pdp-7

I was touching up the [Space Travel article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Travel_(video_game)#Development) on the Wiki and realized no one had answered a question I posted some time ago. I suspect someone here knows the answer.

This image is used in the infobox to demonstrate the graphics of the game:

[image]

What the heck is this? I have never seen the game being played, but that certainly doesn't match any object mentioned in the description. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: ‘Space Travel article on the Wiki’ — https://wiki.c2.com/?SpaceTravel has nothing.

Comment: This might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bZfhKPoKVXg (sry: video)

Comment: One screenshot calls this ["orbit"](https://duplox.wzb.eu/endbericht/sabine.htm#toc4) but the [source](https://archive.computerhistory.org/resources/access/text/2019/09/102785108-05-001-acc.pdf) (p129)does not list any solar system/game objects the resemble this IRL?

Comment: It's now possible to play a version of Space Travel on a PDP-7 emulator.  We don't quite know which game controls there are, or how to operate them.  Here's a video: http://sebras.se/space-travel-2.mp4

Comment: This is clearly the 3d0 orbital of a hydrogen atom.